# The 'Things' tag should be renamed

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tags

[things](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/things) refers to the program [Things](http://culturedcode.com/things/). Makes sense. There was no wiki on this, so I just stumbled on to it. Of the 6 questions tagged with [things](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/things) at least 4 of them give some specifics as to what "things" is.

## **My proposal**

[things](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/things) be turned into [things-for-mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/things-for-mac) or at least something more descriptive like [things-mac-application](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/things-mac-application). My first thought when I saw the [things](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/things) tag was "***what things***?" which lead me to do some digging and put in a wiki edit request. Ultimately, the [things](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/things) tag is way too generic and has the possibility of being misused. It should be a synonym for the new tag or burninated.

Comment: Yes. `things` is ambiguous.

Comment: We have `[office-for-mac]` so it should probably be `[things-for-mac]`.

Comment: Things for mac is actually the name used on its website for distinguishing it from things for iPad for example. Things mac application otoh just sounds horrible.

Comment: By the way: *What windows? What intel? What outlook? What exchange?*

Comment: I don't understand a *Word* you say.

Comment: What *Apples* are rotten? where should I land my *iPod*? Can I buy a bachelor *iPad* in NYC?

Comment: @slhck `word` redirects to `microsoft-word`.

Comment: whose *boot* are we referring to?

Comment: WHERE do{ i goto now()? We should have a contest of writing prose using programming terms. Oh, that's right, we do that already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that this is a non-destructive and tiny retagging task, I retagged all [things](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/things) questions to [things-for-mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/things-for-mac) and adapted the Tag Wiki Excerpt appropriately.

The [things](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/things) tag should therefore be vanishing in the next 24 hours.